# css3 transition on opacity and coordinates at the same time

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I am trying to fade away a div which is moving.
I created a codepen with 4 buttons at the following address : http://codepen.io/3MO/pen/zNadrB
- Show left shows the left side
- Push back pushes away the box (TranslationX after the rotation 90 deg).
- Reset allows to restore the initial position.
- Push back fade is the same as push back, but is supposed to dimmer the opacity to 0.5

The classes are defined as follow:

```
.push-back {
   transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(1000px);
}

.push-back-fade {
   transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(1000px);
   opacity:0.5;
 }
```

the second css class does not work at all, and only one side becomes visible. Why ?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not adding the transition for opacity, only for transform. Also, you do add the classes but don't remove them when add another one, this is bringing some poblems.

Comment: I use transition: time, I do not precise any properties, neither transform nor opacity. I understood it should apply to all.